# ¿Qué significa en Argentina que una persona sea piedra?

Tags: modismos, españa, argentina

Existe una canción de una banda argentina (*Él mató a un policía motorizado*) que se llama *Amigo Piedra*.

He tratado de encontrarle sentido a la letra pero no entiendo qué significa que una persona sea "piedra". Lo que entiendo es que quizá una persona "piedra" es una persona "buena onda", "amable" quizá. ¿Es esto correcto?

Comment: Pues según el DAMER, _[piedra](https://www.asale.org/damer/piedra)_ aplicado a persona significa "antipática", "desagradable en el trato" o "pesada en el trato", pero ninguna de las acepciones aplica en Argentina.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Piedra
   Que da mala suerte. Mufa, gafe.

¡*Que piedra es el Chacho Coudet*!

*Cada vez que su equipo juega una final sale derrotado*.

---

- "Amigo Piedra", sería amigo con gafe o con mala suerte.

---

Diccionario Argentino. Palabras, modismos y mas.

https://www.diccionarioargentino.com/term/Piedra

Comment: También se la usa a la inversa: "Esa persona es una drapie." (Diría que es hasta más habitual y, obviamente, muy coloquial y hasta graciosa.)